# Small confusion in regex at | (pipe)

Tags: regex

when i use pattren

```
"(see|see also) [\w\d]+"
```

on Text

```
see page 
see also page
```

But output Matches is

```
see page 
see also
```

if im interchanged see, see also

```
"(see also|see) [\w\d]+"
```

the output is

```
see page 
see also page
```

I thought both are same. May i know why this is happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing the alternation and leaving `see [\w\d]+` will match the string "see also page" because it is satisfied by `see also`.  The way that regular expressions work with alternation (at least in this case) is that it will attempt to match each option in order with the rest of the pattern and stop as soon as it does so successfully, or go back to the alternatives when it fails.  When you reverse the alternation, it tries to match with `see also` first, but that will fail with "see page."

It would make more sense to write this as `see( also)? [\w\d]+`

Comment: Thanks :) i got perfect approach